# Cropping/centering problems with logos in Developer Story

Tags: bug, design, developer-story

If you provide an image that is taller than it is wide, its height is not correctly scaled to fit the 64x64 pixel box:

[image]

Using very tall images, the problem gets worse (distortion is mine, I just scaled the image to be about twice as tall):

[image]

If you use an image that is wider than it is tall, the image is scaled correctly, but not vertically aligned within the box:

[image]