# Images for Education entries (and maybe any non-logo-sized ones?) can be weirdly big

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, developer-story

I think this is a different issue from [the bug with scaling, which is specific to the classes of entries that assume a "logo-sized" image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320083/cropping-centering-problems-with-logos-in-developer-story).

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/347414):
[image]

Both schools seem to be trying to max out the *width* used, and then setting the height to maintain the aspect ratio.  So the rectangular college logo looks decent (since the width restriction keeps the height manageable).  But the square high school one looks goofy, because the same width cap makes the height aggressive.

I *think* the best solution that still allows for different aspect ratios - we don't want to force the user to find one that's a specific shape - may be to define the fields where the expected image is a *logo* (role, education, etc.), and then set a max *height* that's similar to the college one shown here.

The complication I see with that is that it might require text wrapping when it's square (or has any width to height ratio too low to fill most of the width).

But I think that may be better than the giant square?

Comment: This might just be because I haven't signed up for this, but [your link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/story/347414) appears broken.

Comment: @Tas Yes, that is only visible to beta participants at the moment.